# What are the new Battlefield 3 assignments?

Tags: battlefield-3

Since the last update which unlocked Back to Karkand, at the end of a round I see a range of titles and below each, a weapon and a progress bar, some of which increase as I play.

But it does not tell what they are.

A friend told me, these are the new assignments, but couldn't know the details either.

What are these assignments? What must I do in order to complete each?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to battelog, in the upper right menu click in Missions.

You will unlock the new guns doing missions.

**FAMAS (“Best Friend Forever” assignment)**

- 10 heals
- 10 revives

**L85A2 (“Professional Russian”)**

- 100 kills with assault rifles
- 20 kills with grenade launcher
- Win 5 rounds of Squad Deathmatch

**MP5 / HK53 (“Fixing it”)**

- 10 repairs
- 1 kill with repair torch

**QBZ-95B (“It Goes Boom”)**

- 50 anti-tank rocket kills
- 5 conquest round wins
- Destroy 1 enemy vehicle with repair torch

**QBB-95 (“Let It Rain”)**

- 20 kills with light machine guns
- 2 mortar kills

**QBU-88 (“Specops”)**

- 20 sniper rifle kills
- 5 laser designator assists

**MG36 (“Keep Your Head Down”)**

- 100 kills with light machine guns
- 50 suppression kill assists
- 50 ammo resupplies

**L96 (“Creeping Death”)**

- 50 headshots
- 50 spot assists
- 5 knife kills

**PP-19 (“Familiar Territory”)**

- Capture 10 flags
- Arm 10 MCOM stations
- Play 2 hours on Strike At Karkand

**Jackhammer / MK3A3 (“Scarred Veteran”)**

- 10 kills with PP-19
- 10 kills with BTR-90
- 5 kills with DPV jeep
- Play 2 hours on Gulf of Oman
- Play 2 hours on Sharqi Peninsula

Comment: Not all of them are unlocked in there. Any more info?

Comment: Updated. Source: http://bf3blog.com/2011/12/list-of-battlefield-3-assignments/

Comment: "Destroy 1 enemy vehicle with repair torch".. Hilarious :)

Comment: Note that while the five "lines" of assignments are all active and can progress at all times, each one's "second tier" doesn't activate until the first is done. Example: If you have not yet completed "Familiar Territory", then kills with the DPV jeep will not be counted to "Scarred Veteran".

Answer (score 0):

Note that Assignments are only unlocked for you to complete once you purchase Back to Karkand.

Comment: Actually, this is stated in the question - "Since the last update which unlocked Back to Karkand..."

Comment: Well B2K is not unlocked by the patch, but by your product key. You need the B2K patch inorder to play online, even if you don't own B2K.